# Rename a TeamCity Build Agent

Tags: teamcity

I have inherited a TeamCity server and I am reviewing the configuration. To make it a little easier, I would like to rename a build agent from a long random name to something a little more easily identifiable.

However, I cannot find any options to change the name in the Agent Summary page.

Has anyone got a way to change the build agent name?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to edit the `name` field in the `buildAgent.properties` file on the agent itself:

```
name=change-this-name
```

Depending on where you installed the TeamCity Agent, on Windows the file may live at `C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties` or on Linux at `/home/teamcity/buildagent/conf/buildAgent.properties`.

Comment: Perfect! Worth noting I then had to restart the build agent and TeamCity services. One interesting quirk is that in TeamCity, old builds still show the original Build Agent name, but clicking on them still takes you to the Build Agent, albeit with the new name.

Comment: I've found in the past (at least on Windows) that the agent will automatically restart if you edit that file and connect with the new name. The agent name is cached on old builds in case you delete the agent, you can update `agent_name` in the `history` database table, leave `agent_type_id` as is.